# Container view change view dynamically

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following layout.

[image]

Green and Orange views are extra views added to the view controller.
I want to change the contained view controllers view to be changed according to the button user clicked.

Comment: @IyyappanRavi let me try it

Comment: you are try it my answer or not, its working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I have Answer Using `UIContainer` dynamically show two `ViewControllers` in ios,

I have Create BaseViewController and Two `viewControllers`(GreenViewController and OrangeViewController), let seen below image are

[image]

And `baseView` inserted two `UIButton`(Green and Orange button), `UIContainerView` and the source is below,

`BaseViewController.h` file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *currentViewController;
```

`BaseViewController.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _currentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GreenViewController"];
    _currentViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self addChildViewController:_currentViewController];
    [self addSubview:_currentViewController.view toView:_containView];
}

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)subView toView:(UIView*)parentView {
    [parentView addSubview:subView];

    NSDictionary * views = @{@"subView" : subView,};
    NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subView]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:0
                                                                     views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[subView]|"
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:0
                                                            views:views];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
}

- (void)cycleFromViewController:(UIViewController*) oldViewController
               toViewController:(UIViewController*) newViewController {
    [oldViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
    [self addSubview:newViewController.view toView:self.containView];
    [newViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // set starting state of the transition
    newViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         newViewController.view.alpha = 1;
                         oldViewController.view.alpha = 0;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [oldViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                         [oldViewController removeFromParentViewController];
                         [newViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                     }];
}
```

**Green Button Action is below**

```
- (IBAction)greenViewAction:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GreenViewController"];
    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
    self.currentViewController = newViewController;

}
```

**Orange Button Action is below**

```
- (IBAction)orangeViewAction:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *newViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OrangeViewController"];
    newViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self cycleFromViewController:self.currentViewController toViewController:newViewController];
    self.currentViewController = newViewController;
}
```

its working for me, see the output below,

[image]

hope its helpful